Apps Script to create new subfolder within a designated folder and move uploaded files to new folder upon Form submission
I am following the steps from this post https://support.google.com/docs/thread/185809026/need-google-form-to-create-individual-submission-folders-to-house-the-photos-uploaded?hl=en
It works BEAUTIFULLY when I practiced on my "dummy" practice form with only 2 questions and the option to upload 1 file.
Two scripts in place:
Setup.gs
// TODO You must run the setUp() function before you start using this sample.

/** 
 * The setUp() function performs the following:
 *  - Creates a Google Drive folder named by the APP_FOLDER_NAME
 *    variable in the Code.gs file.
 *  - Creates a trigger to handle onFormSubmit events.
 */
function setUp() {
  // Ensures the root destination folder exists.
  const appFolder = getFolder_(APP_FOLDER_NAME);
  if (appFolder !== null) {
    console.log(`Application folder setup.
    Name: ${appFolder.getName()}
    ID: ${appFolder.getId()}
    URL: ${appFolder.getUrl()}`)
  }
  else {
    console.log(`Could not setup application folder.`)
  }
  // Calls the function that creates the Forms onSubmit trigger.
  installTrigger_();
}

/** 
 * Returns a folder to store uploaded files in the same location
 * in Drive where the form is located. First, it checks if the folder
 * already exists, and creates it if it doesn't.
 *
 * @param {string} folderName - Name of the Drive folder. 
 * @return {object} Google Drive Folder
 */
function getFolder_(folderName) {

  // Gets the Drive folder where the form is located.
  const ssId = FormApp.getActiveForm().getId();
  const parentFolder = DriveApp.getFileById(ssId).getParents().next();

  // Iterates through the subfolders to check if folder already exists.
  // The script checks for the folder name specified in the APP_FOLDER_NAME variable.
  const subFolders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = subFolders.next();

    // Returns the existing folder if found.
    if (folder.getName() === folderName) {
      return folder;
    }
  }
  // Creates a new folder if one doesn't already exist.
  return parentFolder.createFolder(folderName)
    .setDescription(`Created by ${APP_TITLE} application to store uploaded files.`);
}

/**
 * Installs trigger to capture onFormSubmit event when a form is submitted.
 * Ensures that the trigger is only installed once.
 * Called by setup().
 */
function installTrigger_() {
  // Ensures existing trigger doesn't already exist.
  let propTriggerId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('triggerUniqueId')
  if (propTriggerId !== null) {
    const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (let t in triggers) {
      if (triggers[t].getUniqueId() === propTriggerId) {
        console.log(`Trigger with the following unique ID already exists: ${propTriggerId}`);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
  // Creates the trigger if one doesn't exist.
  let triggerUniqueId = ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
    .forForm(FormApp.getActiveForm())
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create()
    .getUniqueId();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('triggerUniqueId', triggerUniqueId);
  console.log(`Trigger with the following unique ID was created: ${triggerUniqueId}`);
}

/**
 * Removes all script properties and triggers for the project.
 * Use primarily to test setup routines.
 */
function removeTriggersAndScriptProperties() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
  // Removes all triggers associated with project.
  const triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (let t in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[t]);
  }
}

/**
 * Removes all form responses to reset the form.
 */
function deleteAllResponses() {
  FormApp.getActiveForm().deleteAllResponses();
}


Code.gs:
// TODO Before you start using this sample, you must run the setUp() 
// function in the Setup.gs file.

// Application constants
const APP_TITLE = "Upload files to Drive from Forms";
const APP_FOLDER_NAME = "Upload files to Drive (File responses)";

// Identifies the subfolder form item
const APP_SUBFOLDER_ITEM = "Student First and Last Name";
const APP_SUBFOLDER_NONE = "<None>";


/**
 * Gets the file uploads from a form response and moves files to the corresponding subfolder.
 *  
 * @param {object} event - Form submit.
 */
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  try {
    // Gets the application root folder.
    var destFolder = getFolder_(APP_FOLDER_NAME);

    // Gets all form responses.
    let itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();

    // Determines the subfolder to route the file to, if any.
    var subFolderName;
    let dest = itemResponses.filter((itemResponse) =>
      itemResponse.getItem().getTitle().toString() === APP_SUBFOLDER_ITEM);

    // Gets the destination subfolder name, but ignores if APP_SUBFOLDER_NONE was selected;
    if (dest.length > 0) {
      if (dest[0].getResponse() != APP_SUBFOLDER_NONE) {
        subFolderName = dest[0].getResponse();
      }
    }
    // Gets the subfolder or creates it if it doesn't exist.
    if (subFolderName != undefined) {
      destFolder = getSubFolder_(destFolder, subFolderName)
    }
    console.log(`Destination folder to use:
    Name: ${destFolder.getName()}
    ID: ${destFolder.getId()}
    URL: ${destFolder.getUrl()}`)

    // Gets the file upload response as an array to allow for multiple files.
    let fileUploads = itemResponses.filter((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getItem().getType().toString() === "FILE_UPLOAD")
      .map((itemResponse) => itemResponse.getResponse())
      .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);

    // Moves the files to the destination folder.
    if (fileUploads.length > 0) {
      fileUploads.forEach((fileId) => {
        DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(destFolder);
        console.log(`File Copied: ${fileId}`)
      });
    }
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}


/**
 * Returns a Drive folder under the passed in objParentFolder parent
 * folder. Checks if folder of same name exists before creating, returning 
 * the existing folder or the newly created one if not found.
 *
 * @param {object} objParentFolder - Drive folder as an object.
 * @param {string} subFolderName - Name of subfolder to create/return.
 * @return {object} Drive folder
 */
function getSubFolder_(objParentFolder, subFolderName) {

  // Iterates subfolders of parent folder to check if folder already exists.
  const subFolders = objParentFolder.getFolders();
  while (subFolders.hasNext()) {
    let folder = subFolders.next();

    // Returns the existing folder if found.
    if (folder.getName() === subFolderName) {
      return folder;
    }
  }
  // Creates a new folder if one doesn't already exist.
  return objParentFolder.createFolder(subFolderName)
    .setDescription(`Created by ${APP_TITLE} application to store uploaded Forms files.`);
}

On my complex form with multiple sections and the opportunity to upload up to 10 files this script breaks down.  In my test run that included 4 files for one Google Form submission, this script created 4 folders:
Folder 1: 2 files
Folder 2: 2 files
Folder 3: empty
Folder 4: empty.

On my complex form with multiple sections and the opportunity to upload up to 10 files this script breaks down.  Would you please edit the question to include details of the "complex" form.
